# como mostrar una imagen local en jsp?

Tags: spring, jsp

necesito mostrar una imagen local.

la imagen esta dentro del archivo

este es el codig dentro del jsp:

[image: codigo]

pero no muestra la imagen

[image: resultado]

Por favor ayuda. 
Gracias.

estructura donde esta la imagen
[image: estructura donde esta la imagen]

Comment: Puedes mostrar la estructura del directorio en donde se encuentra la imagen?

Comment: Esta en la parte inferior.

Answer (score 0):

¿La vista en la que intentás mostrar la imágen está dentro de WEB-INF/views?

Si se asi, no vas a llegar nunca a la imagen desde esa ruta. Yo que vos cambiaría el orden del proyecto, pondría la carpeta img dentro de "WEB-INF" y luego, en la etiqueta img, pondría el src como "../img/log.png"

Comment: Gracias por responder, estructure como mencionas pero aun no se muestra la imagen. la carpeta img dentro de WEB-INF y lo llamo asi                         <img src="../img/log.png" alt=""/>

Comment: Y el jsp que está llamando esa etiqueta img, está en views?

Comment: Si, en la carpeta views están todas las vistas jsp

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente lo que faltaba es configurar en el archivo de webappconfig o webconfig el handler para que pueda leer los archivos de la carpeta local.

```
 @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
    .addResourceLocations("/public/");
    }
```

public es el nombre de la carpeta y debe de estar dentro de web pages tambien dentro de esta carpeta debe de estar la imagen que este caso se llama img.
y llamar en al jsp a la imagen:

```
<img src="static/img/nombre-imagen.png"
```